# Where can I get a high-res photo of the RAT from an A320 Airbus?

Tags: turbine, airbus-a320

I'm working on a project regarding the hydraulics system of the A320 airbus.  I can't seem to find a clear Hi-resolution image of a grounded A320 with the RAT extended out.  Anyone know where I can find one? Or if you have one and don't mind me using it for my project, I'd be much obliged!! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

[Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/) is the photo directory of aircraft on the internet, a quick search turns up this beauty :) You can also diversify your search to A318, A319 and A321 since it's in principle the same equipment.

---

Aidyn Iskakov - Almaty Spotting Club

http://www.airliners.net/photo/Air-Astana/Airbus-A320-232/2419974/

[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [airliners.net](http://cdn-www.airliners.net/aviation-photos/photos/4/7/9/2419974.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Looks good! Thank you!

Comment: @Christina: I'm not sure what type of project you're doing, but photos from airliners.net do have usage restrictions, see http://www.airliners.net/usephotos/ for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Why do you bother looking elsewhere?

AIRBUS has its own [Photo gallery](http://www.airbus.com/galleries/photo-gallery/)!

If you are not lucky enough  and can't find there what you have been looking, ask them kindly ([Contacts](http://www.airbus.com/galleries/photo-gallery/)).

Nothing beats first hand resources!