# What are the reasons for an installed engine to produce less thrust than an uninstalled engine?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, aircraft-certification

Is this only due to the various flight conditions encoutered during operation, such as side winds and turbulence, or are there other reasons? Also, is interference between fuselage and power plant involved?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, these losses are well known and are called installation losses.

Their reasons are:

- Intake losses. In a ground test the engine will be fitted with [a screen to avoid foreign object damage](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/would-it-be-viable-to-install-a-screen-in-front-of-jet-intakes-to-prevent-them-f/14350#14350), but none of the long intake tubes which are common especially in supersonic aircraft.
- Generator loads: The [engine drives generators](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/does-electrical-usage-contribute-to-fuel-consumption/26199#26199) to supply the aircraft with electricity. This can be simulated in a ground run, but often the generator load is higher in flight.
- Bleed air: Some of the compressed air inside the engine is piped to a [heat exchanger and then into the cabin](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/why-is-the-compressed-air-from-engine-compressors-taken-from-high-pressure-hp) for [pressurization and heating](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8408/why-do-pilots-disable-the-air-conditioning-packs-during-takeoff/8413#8413), or used for leading edge de-icing. Again, this can be simulated in the static test but sometimes bleed air losses are higher in flight.

Interference between fuselage and power plant is only to be expected with fuselage-mounted engines. This can be both beneficial (as in the [precompression at high angle of attack](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23840/what-type-of-supersonic-intake-does-the-dassault-rafale-fighter-jet-have/24028?s=1%7C122.8286#24028) and speed on the [Rafale or the F-16](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24010/which-supersonic-airplanes-use-pitot-air-intakes/24017#24017)), or it can distort the flow when side-mounted intakes are operated at a high sideslip angle.

Comment: Also keep in mind that such losses don't help "sell" the engine to customers, and also prevent apples-to-apples comparisons, so manufacturers have a vested interest in having the highest test thrust. It's up to the aircraft manufacturer to determine what other loads they may be applying and how that will affect the actual thrust.

Comment: And on a lot of commercial aircraft, many of those losses are *optional*, in the sense that if you really need max thrust, it is possible to use the APU to provide bleed and generator loads.

Comment: @Harper That's not really true, I don't think.  You can't design the aircraft around not expecting those loads or your APU essentially becomes a PU and you'll need a backup for it.  If the APU dies, you're on one engine, and the other can't keep you flying *and* provide bleed air and generator power then you're in rather serious trouble.  I may be wrong, but I don't think you'll find many commercial aircraft designed that way.

Comment: @J... I don't think we're on the same page.  We seem to be trying to talk about different things.

Comment: @Harper I guess what I mean is that, on any aircraft, you should never *need* thrust beyond the system design. Surely, you can always switch the generator and bleed loads to the APU to get more thrust from the main engines, but you should never *need* to, even in an emergency, I don't think. From a design perspective, you have to design to the true thrust available after discounting those "optional" loads - you can't rely on them being optional because they really aren't.  You *need* bleed air, you *need* electrical power; and you *need* the APU to actually be a backup for those.

Comment: @J...  Are you not familiar with a bleeds-off takeoff? It is a normal procedure for most if not all large transport aircraft today, and fairly routine. If the APU is deferred, you can depart unpressurized, and start pressurizing shortly after takeoff.

Comment: @RalphJ I'm not, and I've learned something - thanks!  I'd imagine, though, that the aircraft *could* still safely take off in those circumstances with bleeds on.  Most of the time you're not taking off at maximum thrust anyway, generally, simply to reduce fuel consumption and engine wear.  I guess I was taking particular exception to the notion of "if you ever *need* maximum thrust" - it's not a question of *need*, this is just a measure for economy, I think.  I was taking *need* to mean a case where the aircraft *cannot* perform unless bleed and generators are off.

Comment: @RalphJ In any case, I'm happy to accept the statement that if you ever *want* that performance or *want* that economy, then the option is there, but for the aircraft to routinely *need* that performance would be an unacceptably risky design.

Answer (score 1):

Static thrust is quite more than in-flight thrust, because the efficiency of any thrust generating engine or propeller is directly related to the incoming flow.

If there's no inflow, the accelerated air will generate more thrust. If there's inflow on the other hand, the thrust will be lower. Non installed engines are doing a simpler work.